Does boot image get updated with build updates?
This article talks about saving a copy of your stock boot image. It was last updated in 2021.

So as you might imagine, if you ever want to unroot, you'll need to re-flash the stock version of your boot image. Since you just downloaded a copy of that stock boot image before you patched it and flashed it, now's the time to stash it away for future use.

Is this valid? If I ever decide to unroot, can't I download the official build image again from Lineage OS website?
It may be a different version by then and work differently, isn't it? Or, as you update your build version, any changes to the boot image get applied as well, or is the boot image not affected by OS updates?
And on the other end, should I store the patched version of the boot image if I am currently running it for superuser privileges?

A different version can work but doesn't have to. Also keep in mind that LineageOS may stop supporting your device then, all downloads may be removed. As boot images are pretty small I would recommend to keep both versions, the stock and the Magisk modified version. Storage on a PC is cheap, therefore I keep last three full images that I have installed or plan to install.

@Robert Well, this might be interesting for some future readers: a recent update seems to have flashed a new boot image, and I have to patch it again: https://xdaforums.com/t/magisk-stopped-working-after-lineageos-21.4699782/#post-89778674
